# How to catch onclicklistener event depending on Button text using java in android studio?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

In my current requirement onclicklister event should listen to the onclick of a specific button and  perform certain task depending on the button text. In the below onclick listener I initially check if the clicked button is buttonCall and then I am checking the button text, depending on button text I wish to perform some task. but below code never check the button text. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

In my code I keep on changing button text with different requirement and wish to perform certain task when the button is clicked depending on the button text and I was trying to achieve this logic in the below code that doesn't works

```
  Button button1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{


    if ((v.getId() == R.id.buttonCall)){

        if(button1.getText().toString().equals("END ALARM")){
        Group group2=(Group)findViewById(R.id.group2); //bind view from xml
        group2.setVisibility(View.GONE); //this will visible all v
        resetTimer();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mention "but below code never check the button text." Are you saying that the second if statement is never reached? If this is the case, is the first if statement reached? Is there equality with the view ID when onClick is invoked? Is onClick even being invoked? It would be helpful to include these details within the question.

Comment: what is button1? is it the same as buttonCall? If yes, does first condition resolve to true?

Comment: @Flash103  First if statement does works ,it detect the button, but in my second statement where I was checking the button text , it just ignore that if statement

Comment: @Batman just updated code

Comment: Are you sure that the first if statement resolves to true? If so, are you certain that the second if statement is not being checked? Or is it just being resolved to false? Have you confirmed `button1.getText()` produces "END ALARM"?

Comment: Sharing @Flash103 's concern, try replacing `button1.getText().toString().equals("END ALARM")` with `button1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("END ALARM")`
Also, kindly make sure that the button text is changed to "END ALARM" before you check the equality. It would be better if you share the whole activity code, where these operations are being performed